# How to calculate multiple object tracking performance metrics

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, tracking

I am dealing with multiple people tracking using single camera in Matlab, and need to calculate multiple objects tracking performance metrics which are MOTA, MOTP, FP and FN.

Is it possible to calculate them using ''classperf'' function which is found in Matlab? or there is another way?

Many thanks

Comment: Anything wrong with the question??

Comment: its doesn't relate to effort, I already have the equation from the paper of MOT performance metrics, but someone just told me about this matlab function, so I just want to make sure if I can go with this function on the right path or not?

Comment: @EBH clearly you have no idea about anything he is asking so what are you trying to do? Pardon me if I am missing something, or did he ask you specifically? His question looks perfectly fine to me and there is no need to provide meta links everywhere you go

Answer (score 0):

If you need MATLAB implementation, go for [motchallenge.net](https://motchallenge.net/) (multiple objects tracking benchmark) devkit: https://bitbucket.org/amilan/motchallenge-devkit.

There is also an excellent and easier to use Python implementation by Christoph Heindl: https://github.com/cheind/py-motmetrics. In both cases you will get along `MOTA` and `MOTP` also more powerful [ID-measures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.01775.pdf).